# MEMS piezoelectric sensor circuitry

Tags: sensor, signal-processing, piezo

I have a question what exactly does a MEMS piezoelectric sensor chip contain. Does it contain the sensor element alone (or) also the signal conditioning circuitry for the MEMS piezoelectric sensor as a microelectronic integrated circuit (nanometer/micrometer level).

From what I understand, MEMS sensor has capacitor fringing plates with a seismic mass and then the changing capacitance between the plates is proportional to the acceleration.

I guess the signal conditioning circuitry would be on the chip due to the proximity.

Also, is it possible to process the signal off-chip as well?

Comment: While you can get older varieties or even in a research context DIY most MEMS devices are designed for easy *application* many now having digital interfaces such as I2C or SPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd typically need some kind of energy flowing into the vibrating structures, so the stabilized supply electronics need to present, anyway.

Since the currents involved are very small, it's highly desirable to place these in the same package to avoid much larger noise currents from external traces.

The signal of interest is most of times "coupled out of" these stationary supply signals. So, that coupling electronics should be close to the MEMS element, too.

Then, you've got a weak signal. You'll want to amplify that as close as possible to the source. So, in the same package, if not even on the same die.

Whenever you amplify something, you want to limit the bandwidth – to not amplify more noise than signal. So, typically, loopback filters are integrated. That's often the first thing that "leaves" the sensor: you'll find MEMS sensors where you can set the bandwidth with an external capacitor.

So, MEMS technology is exactly interesting for the *opposite* reasons: it's **possible** to integrate signal conditioning, and so you do.

If you circumvent that (for example, by replacing the external filter capacitor with an open end), you'll simply not get any sensible signal, because the phenomena observed are much smaller than what's easy measurable from afar.

That is not to say it's impossible to do that externally, but you'd have to do very careful (and potentially expensive) board design to protect these signals from noise influences, and to protect the sensor element from loading.

Answer (score 2):

It *can* contain whatever the designer wants it to.  As pointed out in the comments, the usual commercial chip has on-board signal conditioning electronics, to the point of having a digital interface.

I have worked on signal conditioning for a silicon MEMS gyroscope that just brought the capacitor plates out to the pins, with all of drive and signal conditioning happening off-chip, but that was specifically being done in an early stage of product development.